Unwanted characters after version in assembly properties sheet
Something, possibly MSBuild, is appending a long string of numbers and characters to the Product version in my assembly's property sheet:
2024.6.22.6+9f3a8da557d9ed6941ee2dd3751916eb3ff1cece

It should be just this:
2024.6.22.6


Here's my project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>

    ...

    (other stuff)

    ...

    <FileVersion>2024.6.22.6</FileVersion>
    <Version>2024.6.22.6</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

The official documentation doesn't appear to address this issue. I tried the <VersionSuffix /> element, as well as <InformationalVersion />, <AssemblyVersion /> and <ProductVersion />, but none of those made a difference.
How can I fix this and get rid of the extra characters?
--EDIT--
The problem originates with the auto-generated AssemblyInfo.vb file:
Assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("2024.6.22.6+8ae973ace79d1088bac4753cdea9c07b78f68709")

MSBuild is taking the value set there over what is specified in the project file.
I've been able to mitigate this by using my build script to insert a custom target that removes the offending line of code:
<Target Name="RemoveAssemblyInfoMetadata" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyInfoFilePattern>.*AssemblyInfo\.vb</AssemblyInfoFilePattern>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="powershell -Command &quot;
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $(IntermediateOutputPath) -Filter '*.vb' -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $env:AssemblyInfoFilePattern };
    foreach ($File in $Files) {
      $Content = Get-Content $File.FullName;
      $FilteredContent = $Content | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute' };
      $FilteredContent | Set-Content $File.FullName;
    }
  &quot;" />
</Target>

(Note: this assumes inclusion of the <InformationalVersion /> element in the project file.)

It works, but it sure seems like a kludge. Probably because it is.
If anyone knows of a more elegant way to instruct MSBuild to override the value set in the auto-generated AssemblyInfo.vb file, I'm all ears.

The documentation for the assembly attribute properties (e.g. FileVersion) can be found at Set assembly attributes in a project file.

Is the +9f3a8da557d9ed6941ee2dd3751916eb3ff1cece string a constant or does it change on each build? If the string is changing, does it always start with +? With SemVer build metadata may be appended starting with a plus. Your version number is a date and not a SemVer version but is it possible something is injecting SemVer style metadata?

We're a step closer. Yes, the string changes, although not with every build. But I did manage to track down the culprit—it's the autogenerated AssemblyInfo file and the AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute setting. It's taking precedence over the value I'm setting in the project file. Do you happen to know of a way to override that behavior?

See my edit. I was able to 'fix' it, but I don't like the fix. Surely there must be a better way, but if not I suppose I can live with it.

You will want to disable adding the source control information (git commit id) to the informational version by setting the following property in your vbproj/csproj file:
<PropertyGroup>
  <IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>False</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

